# JQuery Selector for not "wrapped" elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a JQuery Selector which select all img elements which are not wrapped by a specific div (with class .special or .dontSelect)

For example my html code:

```
<div class="special">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <img id="1"></img>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    ....
          <img id="2"></img>
    ....
          <div class="dontSelect">
              <img id="3"></img>
          </div>
</div>
```

In this example only the img with id 2 should be selected, because 1 and 3 are "wrapped".

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
var $imgs = $('img').filter(function(){
               return $(this).closest('.dontSelect, .special').length === 0
           })
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no selector for that but you can select all images and filter them:

```
$("img").filter( function(){
    return !$(this).closest(".special,.dontSelect").length
}).remove();

//Will remove the image with id="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('*:not(.dontSelect), *:not(.special)').find('img')
```

or even

```
 $('*:not(.dontSelect, .special) img')
```