# How do I select all inputs except under a specific id?

Tags: jquery, html, selector, except

What I want to do is to select all the inputs buttons on the document, except those that reside under a specific id.

Example:

```
<body>
<input type="button">

<div id="something">
     <input type="button">
</div>
<div id="something2">
     <input type="button">
</div>


<input type="button">
<input type="button">
<input type="button">
</body>
```

For example, I would like to select all the inputs, except those that resides under the `<div>` whose `id` is "something".

What I've tried:

```
1) $('input[type="button"]:not(:parent(#something))').addCSS();

2) $('input[type="button"] :not(#something input[type="button"])')
```

And other similar approaches

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Selector for not "wrapped" elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924672/jquery-selector-for-not-wrapped-elements)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it like this (relatively efficiently).

```
$("input[type=button]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest("#something").length == 0;
});
```

First, you get all the `input[type=button]` elements, then remove those with `#something` as a parent.

Another possibility is this:

```
$("input[type=button]").not("#something input[type=button]")
```

You'd have to test both to see which is more efficient, but either will work.

Working demo of both: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fjxDb/

Answer (score 14):

You were almost there, all you needed to do was remove the space before your :not.

```
$('input[type="button"]:not(#something input[type="button"])')
```

I know this is an old question, but it shows up first on Google, and using jquery's .not() as shown in the accepted answer is not always an option.

Comment: Why is jQuery's `.not()` sometimes not an option?  This is a jQuery question so you can always use `.not()` with jQuery, right?

Comment: When you want to handle events dynamically, so also on elements that get added **after** you apply it, you'll typically use $(document).on('theEvent', 'theSelector'). There, it's not possible to combine the selector with .not(), while it is possible to use :not in the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works: `$(":not(#something) input[type=button]")`

Comment: I'd wonder about the efficiency of this since nearly every object in the document (except one) will match `:not(#something)`.

Comment: Just give it a random shot... maybe you'll have some luck. Next time, I'd recommend trying it yourself if it already is this easy to reconstruct.

Comment: I don't think that this will affect performance very much; the final JQuery object is reduced by another selector (the `input[...]`). Anyway you can use `div:not(...)`, but it won't match the ones in the body, and you'll have to add them manually to the selector.